# Perl::Find a substring and display a whole word

Tags: text-processing, files, scripting, perl

I have a text file that has some data like:

```
 PADHOGOA1 IOP055_VINREG5_1 ( .IO(VINREG5_1), .MONI(),
 .MON_D(px_IOP055_VINREG5_1_MON_D), .R0T(px_IOP054_VINREG5_0_R0T),
 .IO1() );

 PADV30MA0 IOP056_VOUT3_IN ( .IO(VOUT3_IN),
 .V30M(px_IOP056_VOUT3_IN_V30M));

 PADV30MA0 IOP057_VOUT3_OUT ( .IO(VOUT3_OUT),
 .V30M(px_IOP057_VOUT3_OUT_V30M) );

 PADV15MA0 IOP059_VOUT15_OUT ( .IO(VOUT15_OUT),
 .V15M(px_IOP059_VOUT15_OUT_V15M) );

PADHOGOA1 IOP064_VREFLB ( .IO(VREFLB), .MONI(), .MON_D(px_IOP064_VREFLB_MON_D), .R0T(px_IOP064_VREFLB_R0T), .IO1() );
```

My substring is `.V15M`

I am find this substring and want to display the whole word.

Desired output:

```
.V15M(px_IOP059_VOUT15_OUT_V15M)
```

Please need some help.

The code I am trying is :

```
my $var= '.V15M';
open(my $file,'<',"filename") or die $!;
while(<$file>){
chomp;
@words=split(",",$_);
foreach my $word(@words){
if($word =~ /$var/){
print "FOUND",$word, "\n";
}
}   
}
```

The output I am getting is :  `PADV15MA0 IOP059_VOUT15_OUT ( .IO(VOUT15_OUT)`

I am unable to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing's wrong, it's working as it should, but you've misunderstood how regular expressions work. The `.` means "match any character", so `.V15M` will match the `DV15` in `PADV15MA0` and that's why you get:

```
FOUND PADV15MA0 IOP059_VOUT15_OUT ( .IO(VOUT15_OUT)
FOUND .V15M(px_IOP059_VOUT15_OUT_V15M) );
```

What you want is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $var= '\.V15M';
open(my $file,'<',"filename") or die $!;
while(<$file>){
  chomp;
  @words=split(",",$_);
  foreach my $word(@words){
    if($word =~ /$var/){
      print "FOUND",$word, "\n";
    }
  }   
}
```

This will return:

```
FOUND .V15M(px_IOP059_VOUT15_OUT_V15M) );
```

Your code suggests however that you only want words, so if that's the case, split your input line on spaces, not commas (you don't have any commas in your file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $var= '\.V15M';
open(my $file,'<',"filename") or die $!;
while(<$file>){
  chomp;
  @words=split(" ",$_);
  foreach my $word(@words){
    if($word =~ /$var/){
      print "FOUND ",$word, "\n";
    }
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as follows:

```
$ perl -lsne 'print "FOUND: >>>$1<<<" if /(\Q$pin\E\((?:(?!\))\H)*\))/' -- -pin=".V15M" inp
```

**Result:**

```
FOUND: >>>.V15M(px_IOP059_VOUT15_OUT_V15M)<<<
```

**Working:**

- The regex looks for the pin followed by an opening bracket and upto the nearest closing bracket.